# Jscrollpane and sliding tabs combination doesn't work

Tags: jscrollpane, jquery-slider

I have a test page that I have working with sliding tabs
(http://www.maggies-bayfield.com/wp/temp/old/slider_no_jscroll.htm).
if you click on a navbar item, the page scrolls down to the
appropriate place. this is exactly what I want. however, Android OS
doesn't support overflow:auto etc. and I NEED this to work on all
mobile devices. So, I found Jscrollpane and implemented it on my test
page. it works great (scroll bar shows up on android) but the sliding
tabs are now broken (http://www.maggies-bayfield.com/wp/temp/old/
jscroll_breaks_slider.htm).

Anyone have any ideas or solutions?
Much appreciated!

again:
sliding tabs with out jscrollpane: http://www.maggies-bayfield.com/wp/temp/old/slider_no_jscroll.htm

sliding tabs with jscrollpage: http://www.maggies-bayfield.com/wp/temp/old/jscroll_breaks_slider.htm

Thnx!
August